# Stored Proc with XML Throws Visual Studio Warning (works in SQL Server)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've tried to distill this issue down to the simplest SQL I could make that still shows the issue.  I have a sproc in a Visual Studio Database Project that is throwing a warning in Visual Studio but is perfectly valid SQL in SQL Server.  I'd like to make the warning go away.  Anybody know a way to re-write the SQL to fix the warning?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SampleSproc
    @ResourcesXML xml          
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT S.PlanID FROM
    (SELECT foo.x.value('@PlanID','int') AS PlanID
    FROM @ResourcesXML.nodes('A') AS foo(x)) AS S       
END
```

The warning is:

```
SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[SampleSproc] contains an unresolved reference to an object. 
Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: 
[@ResourcesXML].[x]::[value] or [foo].[x].[value]
```

It's complaining about the foo.x.value part.  Just doing x.value throws the same warning.  I'm not sure what I can do to "trick" VS into thinking it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [SQL04151: Unable to resolve when using the XML Nodes](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/605429/sql04151-unable-to-resolve-when-using-the-xml-nodes) bug report is probably applicable and contains a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround on the bug report James linked is a little hokey, but it does work.  Here is what I changed it to and the warning went away:

```
WITH CTE_Result AS 
(
    SELECT foo.x.value('@PlanID','int') AS PlanID
    FROM @ResourcesXML.nodes('A') AS foo(x)
)
SELECT PlanID FROM CTE_Result
```